# Compile a C code, then check if output is empty and run it

Tags: c, batch-file, compilation

I have this code:

```
@ECHO off
set name=code
set command1="path/to/the/file"
set command2=gcc -o %name%.exe %name%.c
start cmd.exe /c %command1% & %command2%>temp
set msg =<temp
call :CheckEmpty "temp"
goto :eof
:CheckEmpty
if %~z1 == 0 (
%name%.exe
exit
)
echo temp
pause
goto :eof
```

What it's supposed to do is to compile code.c, then test if the output of the compiler is empty, and if it is run code.exe. if it's not, echo the error message.

I just can't get it to work.

I looked at the "temp" file, and it is empty, although it still echoes the error message for some reason. Batch is pretty foreign to me, and the CheckEmpty part is copied from another stackoverflow question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error message is probably being written to the _standard error output_, not the normal _standard output_. To redirect the standard error to a file, use `2>temp`. To combine standard output with standard error and redirect both to the same file, use `>temp 2>&1`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Could you please add an answer with my code with this change, (also please check logic, because i don't know about arithmetic comparing in batch, its weird). The temp file is still empty the way i do it.

Comment: 1. I recommend to use the `\ ` as path separator rather than `/`; 2. remove the space in `set msg =<temp` as it becomes part of the variable name otherwise; and I think there is the `/P` switch missing...

Comment: the `temp` file will never be empty.  Because a compiler will output a message saying the compile/link worked correctly or a series of messages that indicate the problems found.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Comment: this line: `start cmd.exe /c %command1% & %command2%>temp` will have some problems.  for instance `command1` is nothing more than a path, not anything to execute, so really has to useful effect.

Comment: @user3629249 For some reason my compiler only goes down a line when everything is OK, and I'm not sure if it even does that. also i forgot "cd" before command1. So what to do anyways?

Comment: how about posting a clear/complete explanation of what your are trying to do.  Then post which OS. post which compiler.

Comment: @user3629249 that is a complete explanation of what i am trying to do. it's windows(cuz batch) and its gcc, as you could know by reading the code.

Comment: So, you are saying that this line: `start cmd.exe /c %command1% & %command2%>temp` is actually: `start cmd.exe /c  cd %command1% & %command2%>temp.   But the `cmd.exe /c` will only execute one command, not multiple commands

Comment: this line: `set command2=gcc -o %name%.exe %name%.c` leaves a LOT to be desired, like 1) where are the #include files located (normally indicated by `-I<pathToHeaderFiles>`  and what libraries and where are they located, (normally indicated by `-L<pathToLibraries>` and `-lshortLibName`)   Then, to get a good compile, certain parameters should be being passed to `gcc` such as: `-Wall` and `-Wextra` and `-pedantic` and `std=c99` and `-g` (or better `-ggdb`)  You probably also want to save the current working directory in a environment variable, so can return to that directory

Comment: the compiler actually outputs to `stderr`, so need to be capturing stderr, not stdout to the `temp` file (although I would suggest capturing both output streams, perhaps by replacing `> temp` with `2>&1 temp`

Comment: if you remove that invocation of `cmd.exe`, and have lines that look similar to : `cd %directory%  then a compile statement that is 2>&1 temp  then a link statement that is 2>>&1 temp  and check the returned value from the compile step and check the returned value from the link step to determine if you want to execute yet another line that run the program.  (both those return values must be 0 before trying to execute the program)

Comment: @user3629249 can you say the full line with 2>&1 temp? I tried doing it and it just doesn't work for me.

Comment: @user3629249 Also how can I execute several commands and terminate the cmd then?

Answer (score 0):

I am on linux, so cannot test the following,

However, here is how I would write it.

```
@ECHO off
PUSHD
set name=code

cd path/to/the/file

gcc -c -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o %name%.o   name%.c -I. 2>&1 temp
if errorlevel 1  (goto error) 

gcc -ggdb %name%.o -o %name%.exe 2>>&1 temp 
if errorlevel 1 (goto error)

%name%.exe
goto end

:error
type temp | more
pause
:end
POPD
```

and name such a file: (perhaps) `compileit.cmd`

Then execute it via:

```
cmd.exe /c compileit.cmd
```

when calling `gcc`, that are lots of other parameters than can be used.

See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html for details

when creating batch files, there are lots of other abilities.

see: http://ss64.com/nt/set.html for details

Comment: Suggest,  if a more complex operation needs to be performed to create the executable,   Then write a `makefile` and have the batch file have the line: `make -f makefile`

Comment: gcc: temp: No such file or directory
The system cannot find the file specified.
I think GCC recognizes temp as part of the command?

Comment: @AmitGold,  If you look closely at the first proposed call to `gcc`, you will notice that I forgot to include a `%` before the second occurrence of the `name` variable.   My error

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to check `%ERRORLEVEL%` than the compiler output. And don't `start` the compiler in another window.

```
set name=code
set command1="path/to/the/file"
set command2=gcc -o %name%.exe %name%.c
cmd.exe /c "cd/d %command1% & %command2%"
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 %command1%\%name%.exe
pause
```